# gVim wont open skeleton code when creating new file

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I am currently using gVim to code in C++. I've recently made a skeleton file that includes imports, macros, etc., so that every time I make a new .cpp file it automatically adds the skeleton to it.

To do this, I used this line:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r C:/Me/template.cpp
```

Whenever I make a new file with command prompt (`vim A.cpp`), a new file is created and the file contains the skeleton. However, when I create a new file using the gVim, it doesn't contain the skeleton.

In order to get the code skeleton in the file, I have to `:q` out of gVim then `:e` into the file. After `:e`'ing into the file, if I make changes and then `:wq` it says `Can't write viminfo file C:/_viminfo.tmp`.

Also, when I try to open the file I made with gVim through File Explorer (after getting the template on it), it appears as blank file.

How do I get gVim to automatically have the code skeleton whenever I create a new .cpp file in gVim?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I have to :q out of gVim then :e into the file.*"

Comment: I have to exit gVim then reopen gVim. Once I reopen gVim, if I :e filename (:e into the file I just made) only then will it show the skeleton code.

Comment: Are you sure that GVim uses the same `vimrc` as your terminal version? Open gVim and execute `:scriptnames`.  Do the same from your terminal Vim and compare.